# TypeScript dynamically pick matching key-value pairs of an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am using following generic interface to select matching key-value pair types of an interface:

```
interface DefaultParams<T> {
  screen: keyof T;
  params?: T[keyof T];
}
```

and I want to use it with this navigation types so that I can pass respectively matching values in my navigate function:

```
export type RootTabParamList = {
  Home: undefined | DefaultParams<HomeTabStackParamList>;
  Health: undefined | DefaultParams<HealthTabStackParamList>;
};

export enum TenetCodes {
  Energy = "Energy",
  Sleep = "Sleep",
}

export type HomeTabStackParamList = {
  Dashboard: { tab: 'feed' | 'recommended' };
  Activity: undefined;
}

export type HealthTabStackParamList = {
  HealthScreen: undefined;
  SystemsList: undefined;
  SystemDetailsScreen: {
    tenetCode: TenetCodes;
    tenetResult?: string;
  };
  SampleSummaryScreen: {
    range?: Range;
    tenetCode: TenetCodes;
    sampleCode: string;
  };
};
```

But it allows me to use both `HomeTabStackParamList` and `HealthTabStackParamList` interchangeably between `Home` and `Health` keys

Comment: Could you please include a definition for `HomeTabStackParamList` as well in your question?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can paste into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work. That means define everything (e.g., `TenetCodes` and `HomeTabStackParamList`) and show, with code, the issue you're talking about ("it allows me to use both..."). That gets us started. *Maybe* you want `type DefaultParams<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { screen: K; params?: T[K]; } }[keyof T]` but without a [mre] it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work pretty nicely, thanks @jcalz

Comment: Great, I'd be happy to write up an answer but could you please first do as I asked and include a [mre] that shows the problem? You say "it allows me to use both..." but there's no demonstration of this. That will let my answer refer to this code and show a version that gives you the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a strict type check for the screen and params keys based on the corresponding keys in the `RootTabParamList`, you can achieve this by following modification in `DefaultParams` interface:

```
type ScreenParams<T> = T extends { [key: string]: any }
  ? DefaultParams<{ screen: keyof T; params?: T[keyof T] }>
  : never;

export type RootTabParamList = {
  Home: undefined | ScreenParams<HomeTabStackParamList>;
  Health: undefined | ScreenParams<HealthTabStackParamList>;
};
```